# My windows app can not find the default endpoint element for the reference contract to the web-service APIs on client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, service-model

My windows desktop application can not find the default endpoint element for the reference contract to the web-service APIs on client-side.

The client app can be executed correctly on the Visual Studio IDE, but it runs into some problem in the environment on the client-side.

Both server and client are Windows OS, and both run on the same local network.

I've tried to connect to the web-service with Chrome browser from the client-side to the server-side, so I think that we can assume there are no network problems.

If this is a problem related to the configuration, then how shall I do with the configuration file(s) ?

---

I'd been searching on Internet for two days.
But this problem has remained unsolved.

The snippet from the app.config on the client-side :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="RemoteAccessWSSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:49172/RemoteAccessWS.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RemoteAccessWSSoap"
            contract="RemoteAccessWS.RemoteAccessWSSoap" name="RemoteAccessWSSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The snippet from the Web.config on the server-side :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebService1Soap" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    <binding name="Service1Soap" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:49172/RemoteAccessWS.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RemoteAccessWSSoap"
      contract="RemoteAccessWS.RemoteAccessWSSoap" name="RemoteAccessWSSoap" />
</client>
```

The snippet from the '.asmx.cs' file of the web API on the server-side :

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "HelloWorld")]
    string HelloWorld();

    [OperationContract(Name = "AddDouble")]
    string AddDouble(string a, string b);
```

Please do me a favor. And thanks very much.

---

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLoTJ.png)

Comment: Can you post the complete error you're getting please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with my experienced colleague's opinion.

He told me that I should rather add the web-service URI as a 'web-reference' than add it as a 'service reference' on Visual Studio IDE.

Thank you very much !